Relation between quot scheme of birational curve
I am very new to algebraic geometry. Currently reading about Hilbert and quot scheme. I want to know more about the structure and properties of Hilbert and quot schemes over curves. My question is the following:

Does there exists any relation between Quot / Hilbert scheme of two birational scheme? In particular if we have two bitrational projective curve then do the quot / Hilbert schemes over then are related?

Thanks in advance.

The Hilbert scheme is contravariant for flat proper morphisms.  It is not usually covariant.  However, the Chow schemes are covariant for proper morphisms.  Often there are “Hilbert-Chow” morphisms that give something akin to covariance for proper morphisms.
